# How to parse the date formats 01022013, 20130102?

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

I am using System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo to parse the date formats 01022013, 20130102. I can parse 01022013 but I am not able to parse the 20130102.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sampleDate, "MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: Well 20130102 sounds like it's using yyyyMMdd format... or potentially yyyyddMM, but that would be pretty odd.

Comment: `20130102` doesn't look like `MMddyyyy` to me.

Answer (score 6):

You have two different formats, so you need to specify them both when you try to parse them:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sampleDate, new []{"MMddyyyy", "yyyyMMdd"}, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea that there was an overload for multiple formats. I assume it tries them in order specified, so perhaps putting the most common format first would be a slight optimization.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about that. Worry about whether the result is correct: what would happen if you were to pass in "12111112"?

Comment: Yeah, would it be the year 1211 or the year 1112?

Comment: Exactly: it depends on the ordering of the formats above. You may never have to deal with such cases, but my point is: correctness should always trump saving a few CPU cycles.

Comment: Point well made @Rik - thank you for the discussion! :)